# x86 add and addl operands are adding wrong?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, xv6

I working with xv6, which implements the original UNIX on x86 machines. I wrote very simple inline assembly in a C program :

```
register int ecx asm ("%ecx");
printf(1, "%d\n", ecx);
__asm__("movl 16(%esp), %ecx\t\n");
printf(1, "%d\n", ecx);
__asm__("add $0, %ecx\t\n");
printf(1, "%d\n", ecx);
__asm__("movl %ecx, 16(%esp)\t\n");
```

I usually get a value like 434 printed by the second print statement. However, after the add command it prints 2. If I use the addl command instead, it also prints 2. I am using the latest stable version of xv6. So, I don't really suspect it to be the problem. Is there any other way I can add two numbers in inline assembly?

Essentially I need to increment 16(%esp) by 4.

---

Edited code to:

`__asm__("addl $8, 16(%esp)\t\n");`

Comment: Be aware that `printf` most likely modifies the `esp` register. Remember that in C stack cleanup is done by the caller. You should step through this program with a debugger.

Comment: Gdb doesn't work really well with xv6 since gdb can only debug the kernel. But, this is a user level program. So, I have no way other than print statements to debug.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that specifically means `printf` does **not** modify `esp`. But it may very well modify `ecx`.

Comment: hmm, without gdb it's difficult. Instead of using `printf`, copy `ecx` some some "debug" variables and printf these variables after the __asm__ inline code.

Comment: @Jester well, yes and no.  `printf` itself doesn't modify ESP, but the _invocation_ of `printf` does. Usual sequence:1) push arguments on the stack, 2) call function, 3) add value corresponding to pushed arguments to ESP.

Comment: Note that in at&t there is no `add`, it's just that the assembler can sometimes infer the size from the operand. If you want to increment `16(%esp)` by 4, then do `addl $4, 16(%esp)` and be done with it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It does modify it, sure, but afterwards it has the same value as before, and it does not mess with existing locals above the stack pointer.

Comment: @Jester printf is called 3 times so I suspect that stack clean up isn't done after each invocation of `printf` but only once at the end of the function. We'd need to see the disassembly.

Comment: @1729 could you update your question and provide the disassembly of the function?

Comment: `ecx` is a "caller-saves" register in sys-v calling conventions, and thus modified by `printf`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sorry for the delay. This is the objdump. http://pastebin.com/riCgjLMa I have also updated my original code.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? By the looks of it `16(%esp)` is the return address, it's a very bad idea to overwrite that and if you get a crash that might mean it's working. This smells like XY problem, what do you want to do? Note that the return address for the handler is not the source in case you want to return to somewhere else this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @Jester Essentially I am implementing signals. In the signal handler, I am counting the time taken by the 500 signals. So, when the signal happens in main, I increment number of signals. If that number reaches 500, then I increment the return address in stack so that I do not keep executing the exception creating code (division by 0). Then, it exits from main.

Comment: I don't know how it works on `xv6` but in normal unix systems the return address of the handler is **not the source of the exception**. To return elsewhere you don't mess with the return address, you change the actual restart address in the context.

Comment: @Jester Actually I implemented signals like that. So, that the program keeps executing the source of the exception. However, there is no "restart" address in the context.

Comment: I say the problem is elsewhere. The way I read the disassembly it does add `4` to the return address. Not that you ever said how it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105937/discussion-between-1729-and-jester).

Answer (score 1):

1) In your example you're not incrementing ecx by 4, your incrementing it by 0.

```
__asm__("addl $4, %ecx");
```

2) You should be able to chain multiple commands into one asm call

```
__asm__("movl 16(%esp), %ecx\n\t"
        "addl $4, %ecx\n\t"
        "movl %ecx, 16(%esp)");
```

3) The register keyword is a *hint*, and the compiler may decide to put your variable where ever it wants still.  Also reading the documentation on the GCC page warns about how some functions may clobber various registers.  printf() being a C function may very well use the ecx register without preserving its value.  It could preserve it, but it may not; the compiler could be using that register for all sorts of optimizations inside of that call.  It is a general purpose register on the 80x86 and those are often used for various parameter passing and return values all the time.

Untested corrections:

```
int reg; // By leaving this out, we give GCC the ability to pick the best available register.

/*
 * volatile indicates to GCC that this inline assembly might do odd side
 * effects and should disable any optimizations around it.
 */
asm volatile ("movl 16(%esp), %0\n\t"
              "addl $4, %0\n\t"
              "movl %0, 16(%esp)" 
              : "r" (reg)); // The "r" indicates we want to use a register

printf("Result: %d\n", reg);
```

The [GCC manage page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) has more details.

Comment: `asm ("%ecx");` is not a hint, gcc is guaranteed to use ecx **if** you reference that operand in a constraint. See [Local Register Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html). To add 4 you can simply use `addl $4, 16(%esp)` no need for an extra register and moving things around.

Comment: That same page highly discourages the use of the register keyword.  Even in the context of using the extended ASM call it still says the optimizer could clobber it or something else could use it.  So declaring that variable as ecx doesn't mean the compiler isn't using ecx else were in the function.  (E.g. parameter passing optimization to a call to printf())

Comment: Sys-V calling conventions say that ECX is a scratch register. No effort is done to save it in between function calls in OP's code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Indeed, hence my whole point about `printf()` and the ecx register.  There is no telling what that call is doing to the register; and as you have pointed out, there's no grantee that its making any effort to preserve it.  So interleaving calls to `printf()` between inline asm is likely the cause of this bug.

Comment: @Kelmar Your code does not compile. However, I have edited the code by Jester's suggestion. I have also removed the printfs and still does not work.

Comment: The output operand needs to be `"=r" (reg)`.  You're right that doing everything in one `asm` block is the sane way, so the compiler doesn't step on things between asm statements.   @1729: the fundamental problem with this code is hard-coding `16(%esp)`, instead of taking a function parameter as a `"+rm"` read-write output operand.  If your code is inlined into another function, or gcc decides to push/pop another register, `16(%esp)` will reference something else.  If you want to write a whole function in asm, do that.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)...

Comment: `asm volatile` doesn't mean that optimizations around it are disabled.  It actually means that it needs to happen as many times as the source code would run it, and at the same places.  (Otherwise it's treated as a pure function of its input operands.)  `asm volatile` doesn't stop the function its in from being inlined, for example.  Anyway, you definitely need to add `"memory"` to the list of clobbers, if you want to keep using the totally bogus and broken hard-coded `16(%esp)`.

Comment: All correct, I wouldn't personally do something like this.  If I needed to get that deep into it, I would likely write the code in a separate asm file.  As I was uncertain of the scope of other statements or what else the original poster might be doing around adding to the value, I didn't not go into that.  (I don't see much reason why you would want to directly add to a value on your stack like that, if you need a counter you should probably be using a register for better performance, or writing the function in C and letting the compiler do what it does best....)

Comment: @PeterCordes According to the GCC man pages the volatile disables some optimizations on the compiler.  Specifically it tells the compiler that the operation could have side effects that are not immediately obvious and it should not assume that things outside of the asm are in the same state.  In this case we're talking about a memory location getting modified.  If the compiler has cached that memory location in a register elsewhere in the function, it cannot assume that the value in that register is valid any longer.

Comment: @Kelmar: No, that's what a `"memory"` clobber does.  `asm volatile` doesn't imply a `"memory"` clobber; you need both in this case.  It turns out the OP is using this to hack the return address for signal handling, not to implement a counter.  Since gcc will never attempt to modify or read that data, there's no need to tell gcc you clobbered it.  What he actually needs is `__attribute__((noinline))` on the function.  Although I assume there's no danger of that happening if there's no code that calls it directly, but just uses its address to register it as a signal handler.

Comment: To be more specific, `asm volatile` just means that the optimizer can't move it around like a pure function, because of the side effects.  If the side effects include modifying values in memory that the compiler might have live in registers, then you need a `"memory"` clobber.  There are many other kinds of side effects, e.g. running `outb` to set a byte on the parallel port or something, that don't require the compiler to spill/reload every named variable around the `asm volatile` statement.